# Increase in per capita GDP always means GDP is growing?

Tags: gdp, economic-growth

This question was asked in very popular civil services examination.

> Question is : Whether the following statement is correct or not?
>   Statement : If a country is experiencing increase in its per-capita
>   GDP, its GDP must necessarily be growing?

The approach I applied is that, in a country like Syria, if mass emigration happens then population will decrease and at the same time GDP might not decrease with same rate. so this statement will be false.

I know my assumption is not too correct, so ignoring that, please help me arrive in correct answer.

Comment: What do you mean your assumption is not correct?

Comment: I'm not good in such questions/topics, so I'm just afraid if this is right way to think or not. 
Moreover I didn't want this particular assumption to prevent better examples coming from more qualified people here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, but if $G_p = G/(population)$ is the per-capita GDP then $G_p$ increases if the population shrinks or the GDP grows, as you pointed out. So the statement is not correct.

Comment: OP, your logic is correct, The statement is false, because the increase in GDP per capita could be due to a population decrease.

Comment: Thank you @Taufi and BB King . 
I was not sure if this can practically happen, so was wondering. 

Though, I'd love to know if this situation is possible in real life?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating rate of growth of per capita income](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/calculating-rate-of-growth-of-per-capita-income)

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning seems correct.

if we consider that *Gp=G/(population)* and we know that Gp is increasing then we have the following possibilities:

- if *(population)* is static or growing then we can conclude that G must necessarily be growing
- if *(population)* is decreasing then G can be either static or actually decreasing slower than *(population)*. In this case, the statement on the question fails